# How to choose Master daily mission level?

Tags: path-of-exile

My daily mission are always 5/6 levels above mine (I am level 40, and get mission level about 45), and therefore I am more likely to fail them. Is it possible to choose the mission level? Or at least the difficulty (normal/cruel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there is a way to choose the area's level of your Master's daily mission.

As you level your masters up, the daily missions goes into higher levels.
(I had a Level 6 ranger made to go into a Level 40 area to do the daily mission)

The only solution to your problem is to just keep on progressing through the story (or whichever difficulty you are in) and leveling up your character... Or, go to Cruel or Merciless difficulty (if you are not already in it)